# Let $0<\alpha<1$. Prove that $\exists \, 0<x<1$ s.t. for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $\alpha^n < [nx]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, discrete-mathematics

Let $[x]$ denote the fractional part of x. I'm quite lost about how to solve this problem. I suspect the solution is elementary, but all I can determine is that $x\notin\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? It's definitely a non-trivial question, and may rely on some slightly subtle properties of the distribution of numbers mod 1...

Comment: It's a question from Berkeley's monthly math competition, from around 20 years ago (unfortunately no answer is available online). Believe it or not, it's aimed at high school students...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let any $\alpha$ be given in the interval $(0, 1),$ or indeed in $[0,1).$

For any $x$ in $[0, 1),$ and any positive integer $n,$ we say that $x$ **fails for** $n$ if
$$
[nx] \leqslant \alpha^n.
$$

For any $x$ in $[0, 1),$ we say simply that $x$ **fails** if $x$ fails for some $n.$

For each value of $n,$ the set of "failing" values of $x$ is a union of $n$ closed, pairwise disjoint subintervals of $[0, 1),$ each of length $\alpha^n/n$:
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^n \left[ \left(1 - \frac{i}{n}\right),
\left(1 - \frac{i}{n} + \frac{\alpha^n}{n} \right)\right].
$$

Choose a positive integer $N$ large enough to ensure that
$$
2\alpha^N < 1 - \alpha,
$$
and consider the subinterval of $(0, 1)$
$$
I = \left( \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right), 1 \right),
$$
and the intersections with $I$ of the sets of failing values (of $x$) for all $n \geqslant N.$

For given $n \geqslant N,$ let there be $k$ subintervals of failing values having non-empty intersections with the open interval $I.$

If $k \geqslant 2,$ then the lower endpoint of the second-smallest of these subintervals is $1 - (k - 1)/n,$ so we must have:
\begin{gather*}
1 - \frac{k - 1}{n} > 1 - \frac{1}{N}, \\
\text{i.e.} \quad k < 1 + \frac{n}{N}.
\end{gather*}

This inequality certainly also holds if $k = 1.$

Therefore, the total length of all of the (finitely many) intervals of failing values (of $x$) for $n$ in the subinterval $I$ of $(0, 1)$ is at most:
$$
k\frac{\alpha^n}{n} \leqslant
\left( 1 + \frac{n}{N} \right) \frac{\alpha^n}{n} =
\left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{N} \right) \alpha^n \leqslant
\frac{2}{N} \alpha^n.
$$
Summing over all $n \geqslant N,$ therefore, the measure of the set of all failing values of $x$ in the subinterval $I$ is at most:
$$
\frac{2}{N} \sum_{n=N}^\infty \alpha^n =
\frac{2}{N} \frac{\alpha^N}{1 - \alpha} <
\frac{1}{N}.
$$
Because $I$ has length $1/N,$ it follows that $I,$ and therefore $(0, 1),$ contains some values of $x$ which do not fail for any $n.$

Q.E.D.

Comment: This looks a lot like what I was expecting - basically a measure-based argument.  Very neat!

Comment: Nice proof. A positive proof is always better than a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried proof by contradiction? Suppose there is a positive $\alpha$ less than 1 such that for all positive $x$ less than 1 there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha^n\ge[nx]$. Perhaps for $x$ some function of $\alpha$ this leads to a contradiction? Such as perhaps $x=1-\alpha$ although that is just a random suggestion.

Comment: Your suggestion for $x$ fails trivially (i.e., when $n=1$) in half the cases.

Comment: While I was not trying to make a case for $x=1-\alpha$ the statement that $\alpha^n<[n(1-\alpha)]$ fails for some $n$ is not disproved by the fact that it fails when $n=1$ and $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, it merely establishes that any such $\alpha$ must not be less than one-half. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also if there exists such a positive $\alpha$ less than 1 such that for all $x$ lying exclusively between 0 and 1 there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $\alpha^n<[nx]$ fails, then any $\beta$ for which $\alpha<\beta<1$ will have the same property as $\alpha$. Perhaps this would provide a path to a contradiction.

Comment: What you're missing is the notion that for _all_ $\alpha$ there must exist some $x$ that satisfies the conditions.  It's not too hard to show that there are particular $\alpha$, $x$ that work, but showing that for every $\alpha$ there's some $x$ is a much trickier problem.

Comment: But the point of a proof by contradiction is to assume the bare denial of what you wish to prove and show that that assumption leads to a contradiction. Did I state the bare denial incorrectly? Bare denials can be somewhat tricky.